# Scale image relative to mouse position from its center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, gsap

Hello my dear fellows,

I've been trying to recreate the effect: image scales up as the mouse get closer to the center of the image found on https://www.davidwilliambaum.com/

I have been very unsuccessfull so far, as I am not sure how to approach the problem.

I started a codepen with some ideas : https://codepen.io/dindon-studio/pen/RwLwRKM

As you can see I first get the center coordinate of the image, and then i try some dirty formula to scales it up with the mouse distance.
But it is very buggy and not convincing at all.

Does anyone got a better approach?
Deep thanks for you help!

```
var mX, mY, distance, element
element = $('.project')

function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2))); }

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
mX = e.pageX;
mY = e.pageY;
distance = calculateDistance(element, mX, mY);
if (distance< 500 && distance >50){
   var scaling = 1 + (1/distance) *100

  gsap.to(".project", {duration: 0.01, scale: scaling,ease: "power2.in",});

  }
 });
```

Comment: One problem is that the position of the center of the image is recalculated all the time - although in reality it is stationery. Calculate it at the start and use those values. This stops the 'jitter'. I haven't put up a snippet because I don't know exactly what you want the scaling factor to be.

Comment: Make sure you use `overwrite: true` or `"auto"` to kill off the previous tweens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build off from your codepen and made some adjustments: https://codepen.io/Mookiie/pen/qBPBmNe

The higher the `scalingFactor` the closer the mouse needs to be for a size change.

```
function calculateCenter(image) {
  var rect1 = image.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = rect1.left + rect1.width * 0.5;
  var y = rect1.top + rect1.height * 0.5;
  return { x: x, y: y }
}

function getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  let y = x2 - x1;
  let x = y2 - y1;

  return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

function distanceFromCenter(image, mouseX, mouseY) {
  var imageCenter = calculateCenter(image);
  return getDistance(imageCenter.x, imageCenter.y, mouseX, mouseY)
}

function adjustImage(image, mX, mY) {
    var distance = distanceFromCenter(image, mX, mY);

    const baseScale = 1
    const maxScaling = 1.5;
    const scalingFactor = 1;
    
    const adjustedScaling = maxScaling - ((distance / 1000) * scalingFactor)
    const scaling = adjustedScaling >= baseScale ? adjustedScaling : baseScale
 
    gsap.to(image, {duration: 0.01, scale: scaling, ease: "power2.in",});
}


  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
    const mX = e.pageX;
    const mY = e.pageY;
    const images = $("img")
    
    images.each(function() {
      adjustImage(this, mX, mY)
    })
});
```

Comment: Damn! Malcom! Thanks a lot, the
    const scaling = adjustedScaling >= baseScale ? adjustedScaling : baseScale 
is the smarth move.
Have a beautilful day!